# Hyperledger Explorer Shows Empty Data

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, hyperledger-explorer

My Hyperledger composer playground and rest server are working fine, but the explorer shows no data.

Explorer config:

```
{
"network-config": {
    "org1": {
        "name": "hlfv1",
        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
        "peer1": {
            "requests": "grpc://localhost:7050",
            "events": "grpc://localhost:7053",
            "server-hostname": "peer0.org1.example.com"
        },
        "admin": {
            "key": "../fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore",
            "cert": "../fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
        }

    }
},
"host": "localhost",
"port": "5000",
"channel": "composerchannel",
"keyValueStore": "/tmp/fabric-client-kvs",
"eventWaitTime": "30000",
"mysql":{
    "host":"127.0.0.1",
    "database":"fabricexplorer",
    "username":"root",
    "passwd":"******"
}
```

When I check the log, it shows this error:

```
[client-utils.js]: sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: 12 UNIMPLEMENTED: unknown service protos.Endorser
    at new createStatusError (/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:65:15)
    at /blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:568:15
[Channel.js]: Failed Query channel info. Error: Error: 12 UNIMPLEMENTED: unknown service protos.Endorser
    at new createStatusError (/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:65:15)
    at /blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:568:15
[ERROR] Query - [39mError: 12 UNIMPLEMENTED: unknown service protos.Endorser
    at new createStatusError (/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:65:15)
    at /blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:568:15
[31m[2018-02-08 13:54:07.217] [ERROR] blockscanner -[39mTypeError: Cannot read property 'low' of undefined
    at getChainInfo.then.response (/blockchain-explorer/app/query.js:208:33)
    at <anonymous> ....
```

IS there anything wrong with the config? There's no clear tuto about how to integrate explorer with composer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard Development Fabric, I have been able to run the Explorer with the following configuration:

- node - v8.9.0
- composer - v0.17.3
- fabric - 1.1.0-alpha
- mysql - 5.7.21

My config file is different to yours in that I'm using the absolute path to the certificates not a relative path.  My config is below.

```
{
"network-config": {
    "org1": {
        "name": "peerOrg1",
        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
        "peer1": {
            "requests": "grpc://127.0.0.1:7051",
            "events": "grpc://127.0.0.1:7053",
            "server-hostname": "peer0.org1.example.com",
            "tls_cacerts": "/home/ibm/fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
        },
        "admin": {
            "key": "/home/ibm/fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore",
            "cert": "/home/ibm/fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
        }
    }
},
"host": "localhost",
"port": "8081",
"channel": "composerchannel",
"keyValueStore": "/tmp/fabric-client-kvs",
"eventWaitTime": "30000",
"mysql": {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "3306",
    "database": "fabricexplorer",
    "username": "root",
    "passwd": "****"
}
}
```

Comment: I've litereally done your version almost word for word and still get the error `sendPeersProposal - Promise is rejected: Error: 12 UNIMPLEMENTED: unknown service protos.Endorser
    at new createStatusError (/home/ubuntu/bludev/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:64:15)` How exactly did you set up your mysql? I'm following the hyperledger instructions on their github and the postgres psql instead.

Comment: That looks more like a 'connection to fabric' error than a mysql error.  I did pretty much a default mysql install as far as I remember.  I notice that the latest version of blockchain-explorer is configured for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I set up the wrong port for the request

`"requests": "grpc://localhost:7050",`

should be

`"requests": "grpc://localhost:7051",`

Comment: should i do my own specific local host like you? or should it be "grpc://127.0.0.1:7051" like their instructions?

Answer (score 0):

In my environment, just adding tls_cacerts to peer configuration on config.json resoloved the issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49934968/8874164

The config.json that @r-thatcher provided is quite useful for me.