# Hyperledger Explorer is empty with Query - Error: No identity has been assigned to this client

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I recently installed Hyperledger Explorer. When running Explorer, it returns nothing to the browser and gives the error:

```
postgres://hppoc:password@127.0.0.1:5432/fabricexplorer
Please open web browser to access ：http://localhost:8080/
[2018-04-16 08:15:18.542] [ERROR] Query - Error: No identity has been assigned to this client
    at Client._getSigningIdentity (/home/ubuntu/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:1206:11)
    at Channel.queryInfo (/home/ubuntu/blockchain-explorer/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Channel.js:896:36)
    at helper.getOrgAdmin.then (/home/ubuntu/blockchain-explorer/app/query.js:98:18)
    at <anonymous>
```

I tried to `console.log` the output of `blockchain-explorer/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:1206:11` indeed the `admin` variable is `undefined`

It's pretty weird since I installed Composer before this and it runs perfectly fine. All the`crypto-config` uses the default settings provided by the Composer example.

Versions (pretty much latest stable version):

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Docker: 18.03.0-ce
- Node: v8.11.1
- Hyperledger Fabric: 1.1.0
- Hyperledger Composer: 0.19

Explorer `config.json` pretty much default, no TLS:

```
{
    "network-config": {
            "org1": {
                    "name": "hlfv1",
                    "mspid": "Org1MSP",
                    "peer1": {
                            "requests": "grpc://127.0.0.1:7051",
                            "events": "grpc://127.0.0.1:7053",
                            "server-hostname": "peer0.org1.example.com"
                    },
                    "admin": {
                            "key": "/home/ubuntu/fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore",
                            "cert": "/home/ubuntu/fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
                    }
            }
    },
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": "8080",
    "channel": "composerchannel",
    "keyValueStore": "/tmp/fabric-client-kvs",
    "eventWaitTime": "30000",
    "pg": {
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": "5432",
            "database": "fabricexplorer",
            "username": "hppoc",
            "passwd": "password"
    },
    "license": "Apache-2.0"
}
```

Anything I missed / hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: I'm dealing with a similar problem, can you ping me when you find the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but my situation was improved by just adding tls_cacerts to peer configuration ( network-config.org1.peer1.tls_cacerts ) on config.json. I still keep getting the same error on log, but now I can see blocks on Hyperledger Explorer.

- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
- Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be
- Node v8.11.1
- Hyperledger Fabric 1.1.0

  - TLS disabled
- Hyperledger Composer: v0.19.1

According to conversation in Hyperledger Explorer chat, it seems to be a bug that ignores peers without tls_cacerts.
In my guess the below might be the code brings this bug.
https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/blob/master/app/helper.js#L251

Answer (score 0):

1.
Have a look in your "signcerts" folder. Hyperledger explorer will only accept pem file and no x509 certificate (perhaps it has changed in the last version, I dont know, I still use an old version of explorer). 
To get the PEM file from your certificate, pick only the part from -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMII ... till ...1EHbso=\n-----END CERTIFICATE----- and remove all the end of lines (\n) and finally name the file admin.pem.

Probably you will also need to rename your private key file in your "keystore" folder. Remove "-priv" and replace with "_sk".

2.
I don't know if it is case sensitive but the identity you use is "admin" and at the same time, in your keystore and certs path, the identity is "Admin".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

in my case, it's because I forget these steps:

```
cd client

npm install

npm run build
```

Answer (score 0):

Got this thing working. There were couple of issues actually.

```
1. It does work only with TLS. Non-tls doesn't work.
2. The node version has to be 8.9.x.
3. There is one more config file apart from the config.json in the main directory. app/platform/fabric/config.json it has the n/w definition only for the sample n/w/. So this will have issues working with n/w which was not started using the byfn script. Changing this config file allows you to connect to any fabric n/w.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your client  _adminSigningIdentity is null.
you can check for it by printing the client object by :-

1. importing util module ( `var util = require('util')`)
2. printing the client value by `console.log(util.inspect(client))`  or
   by console.log  `( client.getClientConfig())`

If the output is something like this

```
{ organization: 'org1',
  credentialStore: 
   { path: '/home/babita/Desktop/My network/fabric-client-kv-org',
     wallet: 'wallet-name',
     cryptoStore: { path: '/tmp/fabric-client-kv-org' } },
  mspid: 'RepackagersMSP' }
Client {
  _cryptoSuite: 
   CryptoSuite_ECDSA_AES {
     _keySize: 256,
     _hashAlgo: 'SHA2',
     _cryptoKeyStore: 
      CryptoKeyStore {
        logger: [Object],
        _store: null,
        _storeConfig: [Object],
        _getKeyStore: [Function] },
     _curveName: 'secp256r1',
     _ecdsaCurve: 
      PresetCurve {
        curve: [Object],
        ...
        hash: [Object] },
     _hashFunction: [Function],
     _hashOutputSize: 32,
     _ecdsa: 
      EC {
        curve: [Object],
        ...
        hash: [Object] } },
  _clientConfigMspid: 'OrgMSP',
  _stateStore: 
   FileKeyValueStore {
     _dir: '/home/babita/Desktop/My network/fabric-client-kv-repackagers' },
  _userContext: null,
  _network_config: 
   NetworkConfig_1_0 {
     _network_config: 
      { version: '1.0',
        name: 'Network',
        'x-type': 'hlfv1',
        description: 'your Network',
        channels: [Object],
        organizations: [Object],
        orderers: [Object],
        peers: [Object],
        certificateAuthorities: [Object],
        client: [Object] },
     _client_context: [Circular],
     _network_config_loc: '/home/babita/Desktop/My network/artifacts/network-config.yaml',
     _peers: Map {},
     _channel: Map {},
     _orderers: Map {} },
  _msps: Map {},
  _devMode: false,
  _adminSigningIdentity: null,
  _tls_mutual: {},
  _organizations: Map {},
  _certificateAuthorities: Map {},
  _channels: Map {},
  _connection_options: {} }
```

your _adminSigningIdentity is null

you can fix it by  :-

client.setAdminSigningIdentity   method   (https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/Client.html#setAdminSigningIdentity)