# Can't start Hyperledger Explorer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have Hyperledger Fabric running on an Ubuntu instance. I created it using the Composer installation scripts. I can ping it and see it working in the Playground.

Now, I'm trying to launch Hyperledger Explorer, but it fails silently. The log says, `Failed to find a peer matching the url`.

Here's what I have in my `connection.json`, created by Composer:

`{
    "name": "hlfv1",
    "x-type": "hlfv1",
    "x-commitTimeout": 300,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Org1",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300",
                    "eventHub": "300",
                    "eventReg": "300"
                },
                "orderer": "300"
            }
        }
    },
    "channels": {
        "composerchannel": {
            "orderers": ["orderer.example.com"],
            "peers": {
                "peer0.org1.example.com": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org1": {
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "peers": ["peer0.org1.example.com"],
            "certificateAuthorities": ["ca.org1.example.com"]
        }
    },
    "orderers": {
        "orderer.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://localhost:7050"
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://localhost:7051",
            "eventUrl": "grpc://localhost:7053"
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "http://localhost:7054",
            "caName": "ca.org1.example.com"
        }
    }
}`

Here's what I wrote in my config.json for the Explorer. As suggested, I replaced all grpcs with grpc:

`{
    "network-config": {
        "Org1": {
            "name": "Org1",
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "peer1": {
                "requests": "grpc://localhost:7051",
                "events": "grpc://localhost:7053",
                "server-hostname": "peer0.org1.example.com"
            },
            "admin": {
                "key": "/home/ubuntu/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore",
                "cert": "/home/ubuntu/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
            }
        }
    },
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": "8080",
    "channel": "composerchannel",
    "keyValueStore": "/tmp/fabric-client-kvs",
    "eventWaitTime": "30000",
    "users":[
        {
           "username":"admin",
           "secret":"adminpw"
        }
     ],
    "pg": {
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": "5432",
        "database": "fabricexplorer",
        "username": "hppoc",
        "passwd": "password"
    },
    "license": "Apache-2.0"
}`

And here's the full error log:

```
postgres://hppoc:password@127.0.0.1:5432/fabricexplorer
Please open web browser to access ：http://localhost:8080/
[31m[2018-05-16 12:08:39.563] [ERROR] FabricClientProxy - [39mFailed to find a peer matching the url grpc://localhost:7051
[31m[2018-05-16 12:08:39.564] [ERROR] FabricClientProxy - [39mFailed to find a peer matching the url grpc://localhost:7051
/home/ubuntu/blockchain-explorer/app/FabricClientProxy.js:37
        if (this.channels[org][this.channelName] == undefined)
                              ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'composerchannel' of undefined
    at FabricClientProxy.getChannelForOrg (/home/ubuntu/blockchain-explorer/app/FabricClientProxy.js:37:25)
    at getChainInfo (/home/ubuntu/blockchain-explorer/app/query.js:91:34)
    at Object.getChannelHeight (/home/ubuntu/blockchain-explorer/app/query.js:190:9)
    at getMaxBlockNum (/home/ubuntu/blockchain-explorer/app/service/blockscanner.js:152:18)
    at Object.syncBlock (/home/ubuntu/blockchain-explorer/app/service/blockscanner.js:40:9)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/ubuntu/blockchain-explorer/app/listener/blocklistener.js:46:22)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
```

Comment: see answers in this Stack Overflow -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853848/hyperledger-explorer-is-empty-with-query-error-no-identity-has-been-assigned - it may help you.

Comment: I had this error yesterday - on the 3rd line of the file, if you put back "org1" with a lowercase o I think you will get past this error.  I'm now in the possition of the Explorer connecting to my Fabric and Channel and finding the Block details.  It writes those details to Postgress, but the UI is blank.

Comment: @RThatcher do you mean the line with `"Org1": {` or with `"name": "Org1",`?

Comment: @RThatcher can you post is as an answer?

Comment: @ulu he means the 3rd line of config.json ... make it `"org1": {` under `"network-config": {`

Comment: Yes, that did it! Can you make it a separate answer so that I could mark it as the correct answer?

Comment: @RThatcher My UI is also blank because of a js error, which, in turn, happens because the call for /api/channel times out

Comment: By the way, is there any possibility to submit issues/PRs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is in `config.json` - the correct config is (under `"network-config"` it is lowercase 'org1')

```
{
    "network-config": {
        "org1": {
            "name": "Org1",
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "peer1": {
                "requests": "grpc://localhost:7051",
                "events": "grpc://localhost:7053",
                "server-hostname": "peer0.org1.example.com"
            },
            "admin": {
                "key": "/home/ubuntu/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore",
                "cert": "/home/ubuntu/fabric-dev-servers/fabric-scripts/hlfv11/composer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts"
            }
        }
    },
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": "8080",
    "channel": "composerchannel",
    "keyValueStore": "/tmp/fabric-client-kvs",
    "eventWaitTime": "30000",
    "users":[
        {
           "username":"admin",
           "secret":"adminpw"
        }
     ],
    "pg": {
        "host": "127.0.0.1",
        "port": "5432",
        "database": "fabricexplorer",
        "username": "hppoc",
        "passwd": "password"
    },
    "license": "Apache-2.0"
}
```